# how to prevent or stop parent component to re-render in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi Guys i'm trying to create a look something like Bootstrap Nav Tabs but with Vuejs and Vue Router i also want to change the url in browser 

 here is my code for VueRouter

it is working fine but the Parent component(UserProfile) get re-render every time i switch between UserProfilePosts or UserDetails because i know my code going to be larger and this is not a good user experience,Thanks

```
{
    path:'/:id',
    component:UserProfile,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: UserProfilePosts },
        { path: 'details', component: UserDetails },
    ],
    meta:{
        requiresAuth:true
    }
}
```

**Main Component(UserProfile):**

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>UserProfile</h1>
    <router-link to="/username">Post's</router-link>
<router-link to="/username/details">Details</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default{
    created(){
        console.log('created');
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: Try wrapping your `<router-view/>` with a `<keep-alive/>` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Vuex with vex-persist. Vue refresh and reload the html each time it is asked. I am new to vue and this was how I implemented it, though it may not be the best solution.

VueX is the one central source of truth that your components can look for information. It will be easier passing down as prop and all the components just head to the 'store' for information

This stores the information as a local / session storage. For more information check out : https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persistuex-persist

```
import Vue from 'vue'    
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
  storage: window.sessionStorage
})

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
  state: {
    database: []
  },
  mutations: {
    pushToDatabase: (state, val) => { 
        state.database.push (val}
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getData: state => {
        return state.database
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: i'm already using VueX in my application but how the VuexPersistence  will help ?

Comment: stores the information on local / session storage and that the state does not get lost when u refresh the page since the information is stored locally / in session. Do note however that the information stays unless you delete it for a local session. For storage session, the information is deleted when u close the tab or browser. This is eventually up to your own configuration

Comment: Hi Thanks for the idea i made it using <keep-alive> and using if else for the component i wanted to not destroy and using vueX to store all the data in once in store then by just some if else state render it to DOM according to need.